# Amazon Interview:Sum of the leaf node in BST

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Code Which I have written for this :

```
   sumBST(BST *root)
     {
         static sum =0;
         if (root!= null)
           {
              if (root->left != null || root->right != null)
                {
                  sum = sum + sumBST(root->left) + sumBST(root->right);
                  return sum;
                }
              else
                {
                   root->data;
                }
           }
         else
            {
               return 0;
            }
        return sum;
     }
```

I have checked it by drawing recursion tree seems well but Still i am confused at some point I am doing some mistake. Please correct me i am doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it doesn't seem like you are actually adding the sum of the leaf nodes.

In parcticular - the line:

```
root->data
```

Does not actually return the data, just reads it.
Should be something like that in pseudo code:

```
sumBST(node):
    if (root == null):
       return 0
    else if (root->left == null && root->right == null)  
       //add the value of the node if it is a leaf, this step is missing
      return root->data;
    else:
      return sumBST(root->left) + sumBST(root->right)
```

---

**EDIT:**

The problem in the code are as follows (clarifying and explaining further that point  in the answer):

You should return the data of the leaves somewhere - this is not happening anywhere in the code - I suspect you wanted to return it in `root->data`.

However note that the recursion will go to each and every leaf - it is just missing returning the value from each of them.

Comment: But while I drawing recursion tree for my code seems OK can you plz check that just I want to know approach which i followed for my code is working or not...

Comment: @Nishant See edit, I tried to clarify it, it is all connected to not returning `root->data`. Note that the recursion tree is fine - it will visit each node, but it is just missing returning the value of each node.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of such question is mainly focused on assessing the candidate thinking process.

All I see here is a typo error

```
root->data => return root->data
```

and an instruction that is never reached

```
return sum;
```

and one excessively long instruction

```
 sum = sum + sumBST(root->left) + sumBST(root->right); => return sumBST(root->left) + sumBST(root->right);
```

Interviewers always like to get questioned about the problems they give. 
A question like "Is the BST given or can I design a structure that is optimized toward given the sum of leaf?", "How big is the BST?"... Can add a plus and most likely change completely your answer.